# PHPmailer Content-Type: multipart/alternative

Tags: email, phpmailer

I'm having problem sending multi part email with wp_mail() and PHPMailer in WordPress.

This mail header:

```
    $wp_mail_headers = array(
        "From: Test <test@test.com>",
        'Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="b_00cdedc7a5309e22d6d51e1ad7ad886e"',
    );
```

will look like this when sending with PHPMailer, the boundary is gone:

```
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.22 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; charset=
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Should look like this:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0    
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="b_00cdedc7a5309e22d6d51e1ad7ad886e"
```

How to set up multi part email header with PHPMailer?

Thanks!

Update:

How about adding filter? Will that work? For example:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail', 'rw_change_email_headers' );
function rw_change_email_headers( $params )
{
    $params['headers'] = 'Content-type: text/html';
    return $params;
}
```

If filter works with PHPMailer how to add it to below code?
And should the filter be removed afterwards with remove_filter( )?

```
$wp_mail_headers = array(
    "From: Test <$wp_admin_email>",
    "Bcc: test@test.com",
    "Reply-To: $wp_admin_email",
    'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="b_00cdedc7a5309e22d6d51e1ad7ad886e"',
);

$wp_mail_message = '--b_00cdedc7a5309e22d6d51e1ad7ad886e
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
  Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable';

$wp_mail_message .= get_field('order_email_plain_text', 'option');

$wp_mail_message .= '--b_00cdedc7a5309e22d6d51e1ad7ad886e
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><title>Order Email</title></head><body>';
$wp_mail_message .= get_field('order_email', 'option');
$wp_mail_message .= '</body></html>
--b_00cdedc7a5309e22d6d51e1ad7ad886e--';
```

Answer (score 1):

PHPMailer takes care of the MIME structure for you according to what content you give it. This will result in a `multipart/alternative` MIME structure (there's a lot more to it than just a header):

```
$mail->isHTML();
$mail->Body = '<h1>Hello</h1>';
$mail->AltBody = 'Hello';
```

Similarly, there's much more to a from address than setting a `from` header, so use PHPMailer's function to do that properly for you:

```
$mail->setFrom('test@test.com', 'Test');
```

It looks like the character set is not being set properly either. You can fix that with:

```
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
```

You're using an old version of PHPMailer, so I suggest you upgrade.

Comment: Aha thanks! So how to upgrade PHPMailer in WordPress? Looks like I'm using it externally.

Comment: I think Wordpress may be stuck on an old version due to their addiction to backward compatibility with the long-obsolete PHP 5.3, but you can indeed load it externally yourself - see the PHPMailer readme for what files you need with version 6.0. I'm not sure how Wordpress loads its own version.

Comment: Okay looks like I have to take a totally new approach to how the email are constructed. Guess its been working before I wanted to add plain text alternative.

Comment: Probably easier to figure out how to use WP's PHPMailer instance - all these settings should be accessible somehow.